# Make DNVM use setting global (machine)

Tags: asp.net-core, kvm, .net-core, dnvm

According to the ["Version Manager" documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager) (dnvm, ref: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager) I should be able to provide the `-g` or `-global` parameter when using the command `use`.

Documentation:

```
 dnvm use <semver>|<alias>|none [-x86][-x64] [-svr50][-svrc50] [-p|-persistent] [-g|-global]

    | add DNX bin to path of current command line
    none remove DNX bin from path of current command line
    -p|-persistent add DNX bin to PATH environment variables persistently
    -g|-global combined with -p to change machine PATH instead of user PATH
```

Yet when I perform this, I recieve the following error:

```
C:\Repos\X\AbsenceRequests\AbsenceRequests\AbsenceRequests.Data.EF>dnvm use 1.0.
0-rc1-update1 -p -g
Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'g'.At
 C:\Users\OSCHELPEY\.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:1905 char:9
+         Invoke-Command ([ScriptBlock]::Create("dnvm-$cmd $cmdargs"))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], Parameter
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

What am I doing wrong, or am I misinterpeting the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options of `dnvm` will be changed in every beta version. You should be careful by the usage of [the wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager) or [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) because the information not always corresponds to the *current* version of `dnvm`.

If you start `dnvm` without parameters or with the `version` parameter (`dnvm version`) you will see the current version of the .NET Version Manager. It's `v1.0.0-rc2-15546` at me. If you have more old version you can update it by usage of `dnvm update-self`. It uses [dnvm.ps1](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/dnvm.ps1) from https://github.com/aspnet/Home/ for self updating.

You can use `dnvm help use` to see the options of `use` command of the currently installed .NET Version Manager. It's

[image]

on my current computer. Thus `dnvm use` should not support `-g` option.

In general `dnvm use` do very simple things. You can examine folders of `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes` on your computer. You will see directories like `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1`, `dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1` and so on. Every from the directory have his own `dnx.exe`, like `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe` for example. `dnvm use` just changes the PATH of the current command line of the user's PATH:

```
C:\Users\Oleg>dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -a x64 -r coreclr -p
Adding C:\Users\Oleg\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Users\Oleg\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to user PATH

C:\Users\Oleg>dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -a x64 -r coreclr
Adding C:\Users\Oleg\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to process PATH
```

The switch `-g` exist for example for `dnvm install`. You can verify that you don't have some dnx version or uninstall it and then you can install the version using `-g` switch.

[image]

For example

```
C:\Windows\System32>dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc1-final
Removed 'C:\Users\Oleg\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final'

C:\Windows\System32>dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1-final -g
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Installing to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft DNX\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final
Adding C:\ProgramData\Microsoft DNX\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin to process PATH
```

You will see that the DNX will be installed in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft DNX\runtimes` instead of `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes`.

Thus `dnvm` really support `-g` switch, but not for `dnvm use`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explenation. I do have the RC2 (latest) version like you. I verified that. The documentation however once showed the use of "-g" in "dnvm use" - too bad that has been dropped. I'll file a github issue then on their documentation repo that this isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't piped the PATH of DNX which the docs specify you must do in order to add the machine PATH. Please try this and tell us if this doesn't work.